# How to share my Darth Vader winter hat display picture on facebook?

Tags: feature-request, flair, profile-picture, winter-bash-2015

As a part of winter bash, Stack Exchange is celebrating the end of the year with hats! I love my SO display picture with these cool hats! Is there anyway I can save them and then share them?

I initially thought I would share my flair on my facebook timeline (and that would have my display picture with the cool hat on ;)  but on searching on meta I found there is no existing app to that as of now.

I just thought if more people know about how cool the Stack Exchange community is (Darth Vader and Batman hats!) it would be great.

Comment: It's not that it's relevant for the question, but this mask is not [Darth Vader's](http://cdn.bgr.com/2015/08/darth-vader.jpg) but [Kylo Ren's](http://www.blastr.com/sites/blastr/files/styles/width_1280/public/kylo1.jpg?itok=ETWHcuI3).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could just take the screenshot, linking to your profile (or WB site, also you can give [a link to the hat](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/a-new-hope)). There's no special winterbash flairs.

I've tried to "separate" (cause the hat is slightly sticking, but that's exactly the hatz purpose!) your pic with the hat from the page and that's what I've got so far:

> [image]

If you have your site, you can just copy html with the hat and your pic, probably some styles also.